# Compiling standalone tikz picture from other document does not work

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I have a tikz picture that works fine when I call `pdflatex picture.tex`.

[image: picture.tex]

However, if I call `pdflatex main.tex`, which uses `picture.tex`, I receive the following error:

```bash
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/spath/save', to which you
 passed 'red_arrow', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

The `picture.tex` code:

```latex
% !TeX root = ../../main.tex
% File-name: picture.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  spath3,
  intersections
}

\tikzset{
    arrow/.style={
        ->,
        >=late.x
    },
    bridging path/.initial=arc,
    bridging span/.initial=8pt,
    bridging gap/.initial=4pt,
    bridge/.style 2 args={
        spath/split at intersections with={#1}{#2},
        spath/insert gaps after
        components={#1}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bridging span}},
        spath/join components upright
        with={#1}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bridging path}},
        spath/split at intersections with={#2}{#1},
        spath/insert gaps after
        components={#2}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bridging gap}},
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \draw[step=1cm, color=black, opacity=0.7] (0, 0) grid (3, 3);

    \node at (0.5, 0.5) {$s_0$};
    \node at (1.5, 1.5) {$s_x$};
    \node at (0.5, 1.5) {$s_y$};
    \node at (2.5, 2.5) {$g$};

    \path[spath/save=red_arrow] (0.3, 0.7) -- (0.3, 1.7) -- (1.5, 1.7) -- (1.5, 2.4) -- (2.3, 2.4);
    \path[spath/save=blue_arrow] (0.7, 0.7) -- (0.7, 1.5) -- (2.5, 1.5) -- (2.5, 2.3);
    \path[spath/save=green_arrow] (0.7, 0.5) -- (1.5, 0.5) -- (1.5, 1.2) -- (0.5, 1.2) -- (0.5, 2.6) -- (2.3, 2.6);

    \tikzset{bridge={green_arrow}{red_arrow}}
    \tikzset{bridge={blue_arrow}{green_arrow}}

    \draw [arrow, color=red, spath/use=red_arrow];    
    \draw [arrow, color=blue, spath/use=blue_arrow]; 
    \draw [arrow, color=green, spath/use=green_arrow]; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`main.tex` code:

```latex
\begin{figure}[hb!t]
    \centering
    \includestandalone[width=\linewidth]{figures/picture}
    \caption{description}
    \label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}
```

I understand that there is something wrong with my tikz library, I just don't know what it is. I've updated my TexLive to the 2023 version and it did not fix.

```bash
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023)
kpathsea version 6.3.5
Copyright 2023 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.39; using libpng 1.6.39
Compiled with zlib 1.2.13; using zlib 1.2.13
Compiled with xpdf version 4.04
```

### Solution

For those having the same issue, using `\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}` fixed the problem. Using `mode=build` also helped when using overleaf, but it did not work locally. I've moved the `\tikzset` inside the `tikzpicture` as well so it would be out of the preambles. Thanks, @Qrrbrbirlbel for the solution.

Comment: Welcome. I'm sure `late.x` is only a typo because that arrow tip specification doesn't exist with TikZ. Please show us your main.tex setup. I believe this needs `\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}` for the `\tikzset`s to work. The `spath3` library uses L3, maybe something goes awry with catcode settings this or that way. `mode=build` helps but has disadvantages (different font than main document). My solution: Use `subpreambles=true` but move the `\tikzset` out of the preamble. This doesn't need TikZ or the libraries to be loaded in the main document and I don't get any errors.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Qrrbrbirlbel. Yes, the `late.x` was a typo. The `\usepackage[subpreambles=true]` fixed my issue. Using `mode=build` solved on overleaf, but not locally. I think Overleaf injects the preambles automatically or does something different during compilation. Thanks for the answer!